# How do I get the session token within a route handler using NextAuth? api/generate/route.ts

Tags: next.js, next-auth

How do I get the session token within a route handler using NextAuth?
I use the GoogleProvider, I am successfully logged in and am now trying to access the session or the token within my backend

api/generate/route.ts:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";


export async function POST(request:Request)
{
 //NOT WORK
 const session = await getServerSession({request})

   ...
}
```

api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
const handler = NextAuth({
providers:[
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!!,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!!
      })
],callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = await SignToken(user.email as string)
        token.id = user.id
      }
      return token
    }, 
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
        session.user = token
        return session
      },
     
   }
})

export {handler as GET,handler as POST}
```

Comment: Are you looking for token?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need the token

Comment: So please change the question.

Comment: Also which provider are you using?

Comment: @im_tsm i have edit my orginal post

Answer (score 2):

got it done I had to set NEXTAUTH_SECRET in the .env file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I identified while doing it for OKTA. Also added that as comment in my answer.

Comment: I am still exploring the new app directory. Do we need to set `<SessionProvider>` in app directory like we used to do in `_app`?

Comment: You set the <SessionProvider> within your layout.tsx file at app level

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure you have `jwt` callback properly set up. Here is an example set up:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "next": "13.3.1",
  "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
}
```

1. `[...nextauth].ts`:

```js
import NextAuth, {NextAuthOptions} from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      issuer: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_ISSUER as string,
      authorization: {params: {scope: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE}},
      idToken: true, // Make sure you enable this
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, user, account}) {
      // Runs for the first time while logging in
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    // No need to write session callback if you don't need token in browser AKA client
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

2. `.env`

```
NEXTAUTH_URL='http://localhost:3000'
NEXTAUTH_SECRET='some=string##'
...
```

3. `/pages/api/get-token-example.ts`

```js
// This is an example of how to read a JSON Web Token from an API route
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from 'next';
import {getToken} from 'next-auth/jwt';

type ResponseData = any;

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  // If you don't have NEXTAUTH_SECRET set, you will have to pass your secret as `secret` to `getToken`
  const token = await getToken({req});

  if (token) {
    // Signed in
    console.log(token.accessToken);
  } else {
    // Not Signed in
    res.status(401);
  }
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: As I said before, I use Route Handler: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers. I have implemented as explained in the convention. So I don't use NextApiRequest or NextApiResponse. Hence my question

Comment: I see, let me check with that too.